# ¿Es el castellano filipino similar al castellano de España?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, españa, cultura-de-masas

Mi abuela me dijo que cuando era una chica, siempre ella oyó a las personas mayores hablando castellano y era en el año 1930.

Ella me dijo que nuestro castellano es mejor que el de Latinoamérica porque la manera en que pronunciamos las palabras es similar a la manera en que lo pronuncian los españoles.

Me pregunto, si es la verdad.

Comment: Tal y como comenta guifa en su espléndida respuesta, deberías definir qué es "mejor". De lo contrario, la pregunta es demasiado amplia. También sería bueno que editaras para que el título y el cuerpo de la pregunta coincidan, pues en el título preguntas si es similar y en el cuerpo si es mejor o no. Cierro la pregunta como demasiado genérica, pero como paso previo a que la edites y fijes para conseguir que luzca correctamente. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno, primero hay que definir lo que se quiere decir con pronunciar «mejor».  La pronunciación es, quizás, la parte más saliente de un dialecto.  Hay que tener en cuenta que un dialecto, regido internamente por ciertas normas, no puede ser ni mejor ni peor que otro — simplemente es *diferente* de los otros.

Los latinoamericanos no hacen distinción entre la *s* y la *z* por razones históricas que se funden en evoluciones lingüísticas que estaban en puntos diferentes de desarrollo al zarpar los andaluces para las Américas.  No podemos decir que es «peor» esta pronunciación, simplemente es diferente (si bien puede hacer que algunas palabras suenen iguales, raramente se dificulta la comprensión).  E incluso con este sonido de la *S*, el hecho de que las mías se pronuncien apicoalveolarmente (suenan algo como la *sh* de inglés sin ser igual) no se considera ni más ni menos correcto que una ese que una puramente alveolar (como la *s* de inglés, escúchese la pronunciación mejicana) o, al final de sílabas, a una que se aspira (como la *h* de inglés) o incluso que se muda («pronunciándose» por medio de una extensión de la vocal anterior).<sup>1</sup>.

Lo que sí podemos decir es que *dentro* de cada dialecto (y a veces, tras todos los dialectos) hay ciertos rasgos que pertenecen a un registro cotidiano, otro culto, y a veces uno esmerado.  Como ejemplo tenemos la *D*, que se suele perderse como regla en varios contextos en registros «bajos» (pero es algo sistemático y casi panhispánico).  No obstante, no pertenece a la pronunciación culta en la mayoría de los dialectos y nunca a la esmerada.  El grupo *ps* solo se suena la *P* en la esmerada, aunque nadie diría que es incorrecta la falta de *P*.

Así que no podemos hablar de lo bueno o malo de la pronunciación para los nativos (para los no nativos, es otra cuestión).

Dicho esto, escuchemos unos [hablantes filipinos nativos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSC7D5ahyyU) para ver qué hay.

Lo que noto es que hacen clara distinción *ll/y* como se hace en algunas zonas andinas y españolas.  Unos, pero no la mayoría, hacen distinción *s/z*, que puede ser por existir variantes regionales, tener antepasados nativos de varios dialectos, o por haber estudiado en sitios diferentes.  No parece haber nada único vocálicamente (hay algunos dialectos que reducen el sistema vocálico a tres).

La verdad es que me suena más a ciertos acentos mejicanos con pronunciación cuidada que a algún acento peninsular.  Si recuerdo bien (y que me corrija alguien si me equivoco), la mayoría de los barcos españoles habrían partido de Méjico al ir a las Filipinas y así que tendría razón tal enlace fonético.

---

<sup>1. De hecho, mi *ese* se convierte en una fricativa uvular ante algunos sonidos velares)</sup>

Comment: La frase _por razones históricas que se funden en evoluciones lingüísticas que estaban en puntos diferentes de desarrollo_ me suena forzada, pero no acabo de encontrar la manera de mejorarla : )